# How can I extract logic to viewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm

In my fragment I have next code:

```
etAuthorName.doAfterTextChanged {
    viewModel.quoteAuthor.value = it?.toString()
}

viewModel.quoteAuthor.observe(this, Observer<String> {
    if (etAuthorName.text.toString() != it) {
        etAuthorName.setText(it)
    }
})
```

How i can extract this logic:`if (etAuthorName.text.toString() != it)` to my viewModel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use databinding in this case, learn more here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding

Edit: You can try something like this:

In your ViewModel class:

```
@get:Bindable
var bindetAuthorName: String = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.bindetAuthorName)
    }
    get() = field

fun comparison(){
    if(bindetAuthorName != quoteAuthor){
        bindetAuthorName = quoteAuthor
    }
}
```

in your xml edittext/ textview:

```
<Edittext
 .....
 android:text="@={viewModel.bindetAuthorName}"/>
```

and whenever your quoteAuthor value is updating you can call comparison(). I hope this helps!

Comment: yes, i can, but i want to extract this logic in my viewModel and after display text without any logic in xml with dataBinding

Comment: You already have "quoteAuthor" in your viewmodel and you can have text from "etAuthorName" using databinding in your viewmodel so there you can make the same comparison and if you are using two way databinding then you can set text on "etAuthorName" from viewmodel directly.

Comment: I don't want to make a comparison in xml
I want to have all the logic in the view model so I can test it later

Comment: i was too talking about having a comparison in viewmodel.

Comment: sorry but i didn't see comparison in viewModel, can u give example please?

Comment: @get:Bindable - unresolved reference and what does it do `notifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: you need to add databinding to your android project: use this link https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Transformations.distinctUntilChanged` add this inside viewmodel and listen inside your fragment instead observer
quoteAuthor

```
val authorDistinct = Transformations.distinctUntilChanged(quoteAuthor)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to really move your logic to ViewModel

You can change it to this

Fragment

```
etAuthorName.doAfterTextChanged {
    viewModel.triggerQuoteAuthor(etAuthorName.text.toString(), it?.toString())
}

viewModel.quoteAuthor.observe(this, Observer<String> {
    etAuthorName.setText(it)
})
```

ViewModel

```
fun triggerQuoteAuthor(beforeText: String, afterText: String) {
   if (beforeText != afterText) {
      quoteAuthor.value = afterText
   }
}
```